# How to Send DTMF in iOS4

Tags: iphone, dtmf

Is it possible to send dtmf from iPhone application in background state after connecting the call?

I don't want to use pause and wait. I tried to find from CoreTelephony.framework but didn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

No, apps can't interact with phone calls.